# Triming strings and char

Tags: string, vb.net, substring

I'm working on mini program. I have a List of Strings. I'm reading strings from .txt file, and if i have a word that contains 4 and more char then read it. Ok, that's i what is working. Then i need to write all strings (words) in another file, and it's working, but i have problem.

For example i have a word School (6char) and i need trim some char from words. For example

School = chool, hool, etc..
Program = rogram, ogram, gram, etc...

I need to get something like this, here's the code. My code is only working for first char, but not for other in the loop.

For example i will get Program = rogram, but not ogram, gram, etc...
My question is, how to get all trim words from my list of words in input .txt file i have for example:

Program,
school,
etc

and in output .txt file i need to get something like this:
rogram,
ogram,
gram,
chool,
hool,

Here's the code.

```
Dim path As String = "input_words.txt"
    Dim write As String = "trim_words.txt"
    Dim lines As New List(Of String)


    'reading file'
    Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(path)
        Do While sr.Peek() >= 4
            lines.Add(sr.ReadLine())
        Loop
    End Using

    'writing file'

    Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(write)

        For Each line As String In lines
            sw.WriteLine(line.Substring(1, 5))
        Next
    End Using
```

Comment: And whats the question?

Comment: How to get another trim words like
Program = rogram, ogram, gram, etc..

Comment: `Dim str As String = Program Dim result as string = str.Substring(str.length - 4,4)`

Comment: it's working, but i wanna get all words.

If i have word Program then must be
rogram
ogram
gram
etc

I only get rogram

Comment: You say you want to cut the word and then you want to get only 4 letters. can you try explain what you want please

Comment: I have a list of words in .txt file program,school,etc...
output results in .txt need to be something like this:
rogram,
ogram,
gram,
chool,
hool,

Answer (score 0):

### The While Loop

A simple way to approach the problem is to use a `While` loop while the length is bigger than 4

Here while our current string is more than 4 length:

- We write it
- We remove the first character

  ```
  For Each line As String In lines
      Dim current As String = line
      While current.Length > 4
          Console.Write(current & ",")
          current = current.Remove(0, 1)
      End While
      Console.Write(current & vbNewLine)
  Next
  ```

---

### The For Loop

The second way to approach this is using a `For` loop where the idea is from the length of the current word to (5) applying a last -1 :

- We write it
- We remove the first character

  ```
  For Each line As String In lines
      Dim current As String = line
      For i As Integer = line.Length To 5 Step -1
          Console.Write(current & ",")
          current = current.Remove(0, 1)
      Next
      Console.Write(current & vbNewLine)
  Next
  ```

Comment: That's it! I know where's my mistake. Thanks a lot!

If i wanna write something like this Program = rogram, ogram.

Now is program,rogram,ogram,etc...

Comment: @megatron1986 then try to figure it out is very easy... And remember put the answer as done if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

I made a different solution. Because i needed to limited to 4 char i made this.

```
Dim path As String = "input_words.txt"
Dim write As String = "trim_words.txt"
Dim lines As New List(Of String)

'reading file'
Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(path)
    Do While sr.Peek() >= 4
        lines.Add(sr.ReadLine())
    Loop
End Using

'writing file'

Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(write)

    For Each line As String In lines
         Dim iStringLength = line.Length
         Dim iPossibleStrings = iStringLength - 5

            For i = 0 To iPossibleStrings                    
                Console.WriteLine(line.Substring(i, 4))
            Next
    Next
End Using
```

Tnx for help @Mederic!